# Convert from NStimeInterval to CMTime accurately

Tags: objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, avplayer, nstimeinterval, cmtime

I am using two players one is `MPMoviePlayerController` and the other is `AVPlayer`. henever `MPMoviePlayerController` is seeked, it sets the time to `AVPlayer`. Everything is working fine. While converting `MPMoviePlayerController` current time to `CMTime` it is rounding off ex:(if mpplayer time is 11.80132 it is rounding to 11).

Without rounding off, how can we set the time to `AVPlayer`?

Code for getting mpplayer time and sending to `AVPlayer` class

```
[avplayerClass  setCurrentTime:[self.videoPlayer currentPlaybackTime]];
NSLog(@"CurrentTime:%f",[self.videoPlayer currentPlaybackTime]);//11.801345
```

Code in `AVPlayer` class and converting time to `CMTime`

```
-(void)setCurrentTime:(NSTimeInterval)seekTime
{
    CMTime seekingCM = CMTimeMake(seekTime, 1);
    [self.player seekToTime:seekingCM 
            toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero 
             toleranceAfter:kCMTimePositiveInfinity];
    [self.player seekToTime:seekingCM];
    NSLog(@"Current time123ns%%%%%%:%f",CMTimeGetSeconds(seekingCM));//11
    NSLog(@"Current time123ns%%%%%%:%f",seekTime);//11.801345
}
```

Comment: Got the answer 
If I replace CMTime seekingCM = CMTimeMake(seekTime, 1); with this 
         
     CMTime seekingCM = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(seekTime, 1000000);
its working fine

Comment: You should post that as an answer.

Comment: is there a constant for this number?

Answer (score 7):

Try this :

```
  CMTime seekingCM = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(playbackTime, 1000000);
```